# Laravel 5 Iterate and Limit models returned from Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Using L5 I have a "Car" model and a "Brand" model.

In my Brand model I have a hasMany relationship for Car, so I can do `$brand->cars` and get all of the cars in my DB for that brand.

This works well, but I will never need to return all of them, I will always be filtering, limiting, or iterating over them.

In my controller I can do `$brand->cars->take(20)`, which correctly returns 20 results, but inspecting the mysql query I can see that there is no 'limit' in the query itself which seems pretty intensive when you have millions of possible results.

Is there a way to iterate and limit directly on a relationship, or just I just abbandon the relationship and just use eloquent directly:

```
$brand::where('year','>',2010)->take(20)->get()?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [Eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading) what you are looking for.

```
Brand::with('cars')->take(20)->get();
```

if you need to filter cars based on any field, for example 'year':

```
Brand::whereHas('cars', function($q) use($year)
{
    $q->where('year', '>', $year);

})->with('cars')->take(20)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use this:

```
$brand->cars()->take(20)->get();
```